# Mysql one row left join

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables :

```
product_list :
id_list | name_product  | price |
1       |    test01     |   20  |
10      |    test02     |   50  |


people :

people_id | people_use_product  | people_list
35        |   test01            | 1
36        |   test02            | 1
```

They have access to the list id 1 and 10. But the same product can be in both row. ( because the list can be used for many list people ).
 I have to get only one row. ( = the price of the product )

```
SELECT * FROM people
INNER JOIN product_list ON (id_list=1 or id_list=10)
WHERE people_list = 1
LIMIT 0,100
```

How can I have only one row ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of expected output to clarify what your question means?

Comment: LIMIT 0,1 perhaps? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request is wrong. You did not specified an adequate [join condition](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html). Your JOIN is actually making a cartesian product of the two tables, that's all.

If people.people_list is your foreign key to product_list :

```
SELECT * FROM people
INNER JOIN product_list ON (id_list = people_list) -- valid JOIN condition between two tables
WHERE ids_list = 1
```

may be closer to your needs.

However, I don't really understand your data structure and your real needs so you'll have to refine the query a bit, I guess...

Comment: yeah, I forgot about the join.Edited